# Error with case_when within mutate function: input must be vector

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, case-when

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `chldwork`.
 x Input must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
   ℹ Input `chldwork` is `case_when(...)`.
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occur
```

I keep getting this error when I try running this code:

```
d5clean <- d5clean %>% 
  mutate(chldwork = case_when(is.na(curjobr5) & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 0,
                              is.na(curjobr5) & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              is.na(curjobr5) & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              is.na(curjobr5) & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              is.na(curjobr5) & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              is.na(curjobr5) & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              is.na(curjobr5) & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              is.na(curjobr5) & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & is.na(wrmm12r5) & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 0,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & is.na(wrmm12r5) & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & is.na(wrmm12r5) & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & is.na(wrmm12r5) & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & is.na(wrmm12r5) & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & is.na(wrmm12r5) & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5== 0 & is.na(wrno12r5) & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 0,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5== 0 & is.na(wrno12r5) & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5== 1 & is.na(wrno12r5) & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5== 1 & is.na(wrno12r5) & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5== 0 & is.na(wrno12r5) & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5== 0 & is.na(wrno12r5) & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5==0 & wrno12r5 == 0 & is.na(wrow12r5) ~ 0,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5==0 & wrno12r5 == 1 & is.na(wrow12r5) ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5==1 & wrno12r5 == 1 & is.na(wrow12r5) ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5==1 & wrno12r5 == 1 & is.na(wrow12r5) ~ 0,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5==0 & wrno12r5 == 0 & is.na(wrow12r5) ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5==1 & wrno12r5 == 0 & is.na(wrow12r5) ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5==1 & wrno12r5 == 1 & is.na(wrow12r5) ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 0,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 ==  ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 1  & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 0 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 1 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              curjobr5 == 0 & wrmm12r5 == 0 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 == 1 ~ 1,
                              TRUE ~ as.numeric(88)))
```

I'm trying to combine multiple work variables into one work variables with several non-random missing values. Any ideas on how to make it work?

I was able to run this code fine:

```
d4clean <- d4clean %>% 
  mutate(chldwork = case_when(curjobr4 == 0 & wrbf12r4 == 0 ~ 0, #condition 1
                              curjobr4 == 1 & wrbf12r4 == 1 ~ 1, #condition 2
                              curjobr4 == 1 & wrbf12r4 == 0 ~ 1, #condition 3
                              curjobr4 == 0 & wrbf12r4 == 1 ~ 1, #condition 4
                              is.na(curjobr4) & wrbf12r4 == 1 ~ 1, #condition 5
                              is.na(curjobr4) & wrbf12r4 == 0 ~ 0, #condition 6
                         TRUE ~ 99)) #all other cases
```

Also, I'm not sure if this includes all of the correct cases I'd need to merge. I'm going a little cross-eyed at this point.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Try to minimize as much code as possible and then use `dput` or the `reprex` package to produce an easy to understand, repducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the lines, the value to be compared is missing

```
...
curjobr5 == 1 & wrmm12r5 == 1 & wrno12r5 == 0 & wrow12r5 ==  ~ 1,
                                                            ^
...
```

which caused the error

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel like the majority of my errors are typos like this but I've been staring at it for so long that I can't see it.

Comment: @shaq1993 it may be better to use an `IDE` which would show the errors